# Fast file-based persistent queue for Java

Tags: java

I am developing a caching solution which requires to store huge number of items (billions), that are not going to fit into heap. So I am looking for a queue which can persist its content into filesystem. General requirements:

- Read from head, write to tail, no iterators, no searches, no random access or modifications are required.
- Can keep billions of items
- Every item is a small POJO, but serialization is not a problem, so byte arrays are ok.
- Strongly consistence is not required, but desired. The content of the queue can be lost after application restart, but better if it is not.
- It should be a library or code that I can link to my project, not a tool or a product runs separately.
- Good performance for the requirements above.

Will very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut, thanks for your suggestion. kafka (and ActiveMQ) doesn't look light - they are clustered and need some server. I afraid they will bring additional overhead.

Comment: You can use ActiveMQ as a library, using the "JVM" transport for inter-thread communication. See http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html

Comment: I've been using http://square.github.io/tape/ with much success. Highly recommended.

Comment: Beware my friend! Some type of queues defined in http://square.github.io/tape/ are not threadsafe.